# Created PFX certificate but encryption is not enabled

Tags: powershell, certificate

I created a PFX certificate using Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt in the following way;

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=mycert" -sky exchange "mycert.cer" -sv "mycert.pvk"
pvk2pfx -pvk "mycert.pvk" -spc "mycert.cer" -pfx "mycert.pfx" -pi [password]
```

Then I use PowerShell to interrogate the certificate

```
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate [Location]
$cert.Verify()
# Returns 'False'
```

How can I get this certificate to be used for encryption?

### Update

@root suggested using `Import-PfxCertificate` command. This is what happens when I run it.

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath [Path]
Import-PfxCertificate : The PFX file you are trying to import requires either a different password or membership in an Active Directory principal to which it is protected.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath [...]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-PfxCertificate], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.Im 
   portPfxCertificate
```

### Further Update

@McDonald's suggested a secure method to pass the password to the `Import-PfxCertificate` command. This is what I tried;

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath [Path] -Password (Get-Credential).Password
$cert = dir cert:\localmachine\my | where { $_.Thumbprint -eq [Thumbprint] } | Select-Object
$cert.Verify()
```

Still returns false. Any more clues?

Comment: [Import-PfxCertificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848625(v=wps.630).aspx) ?

Comment: @root I get that is a PowerShell command. How does it help me? Do you have an example?

Comment: There are three examples at the bottom of that link.

Comment: It would help if you said something along the lines of "certificates have to be installed in your certificate store in order to use them for encryption", if that is actually the case, rather than just linking me to the documentation for a specific command that does not give me a reason why `$cert.Verify()` returns false. However, due to this new error I experienced, I don't think this is actually my problem. Rather, the certificate is configured incorrectly. My question is about why the certificate is configured incorrectly.

Comment: This may simply just be a password issue.... Give this syntax a shot (change what's applicable for your system though obviously) and see if this makes a difference for you, please report back to me your results.... `Import-PfxCertificate –FilePath C:\mycert.cer cert:\localMachine\my -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "[Password]" -Force –AsPlainText)`.... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/import-pfxcertificate

Comment: Well done @McDonald's! With your help I managed to do it with `(Get-Credential).Password` to avoid having to type it out as plaintext. However, this still didn't fix my problem (see above).

Comment: @McDonald's it is an instance of X509Certificate2 class, part of .NET framework. When you call `New-SelfSignedCertificate` or `Select-Object` from an item the certificate store, this is what you get back. Here is documentation for Verify: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: From that link you posted in the above comment, I thought it was interesting where in the the **Remark** section where it says.... ***This method builds a simple chain for the certificate and applies the base policy to that chain. If you need more information about a failure, validate the certificate directly using the [X509Chain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain(v=vs.110).aspx) object.*** ..... hmmmmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60625/discussion-between-steztric-and-mcdonalds).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Verify`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify(v=vs.110).aspx) method checks whether a certificate is trusted. To see exactly why verification is failing, we need to build the chain:

```
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath .\mycert.pfx
$chain = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain
$chain.Build($cert)
$chain.ChainStatus
```

When I repeat your steps and run those commands, I get a [status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chainstatusflags(v=vs.110).aspx) of `UntrustedRoot`. This means that verification failed because the certificate is not signed by a trusted certification authority, which makes sense given that we're self signing it (the `-r` switch on `makecert`).

To make the certificate verify, import it into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store:

```
Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\Root -FilePath .\testcert.pfx -Password (Read-Host 'Password' -AsSecureString)
```

Enter the PFX password, accept the big warning dialog, and the certificate will be added. Then verification will pass. If you prefer GUIs, `certmgr.msc` will do the job.

---

You can use the RSA parameters just fine without the certificate being trusted by your computer, though. Let's say the number 137 is a secret message to the holder of the private key. We can use the public key to encrypt our message:

```
$public = Get-PfxCertificate .\mycert.cer
$public.PublicKey.Key.Encrypt(@(137), $false)
```

Then somehow the resulting encrypted big array of bytes (call it `$message`) gets to the private key holder, who recovers the original number:

```
$private = Get-PfxCertificate .\mycert.pfx
$private.PrivateKey.Decrypt($message)
```

Usually something more interesting/advanced ([see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)) would be done with the keys. The point is, applications can use the certificate without it being trusted by the machine.

Comment: Nice Ben, it seems you used the advice of the MSDN post and showed how to **validate the certificate directly using the X509Chain object** and then gave some other pointers.

Comment: @BenN thanks for the pointers. So the main problem of what I was trying to get to was that the certificate was not trusted by the host and needs to be installed as a root certificate.

Comment: The dynamic reading of password is just what I was looking for - very nice: *(Read-Host 'Password' -AsSecureString)*

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted @BenN's answer as that is the actual solution. I wanted to pull together the things I have learned into a cohesive process, so that it is easy for others to generate certificates for encryption.

Step 1: Create a certificate

```
$publicCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $dnsName `
    -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

The certificate is not trusted

```
$publicCert.Verify()
False
```

Step 2: Export the PFX certificate

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $publicCert -FilePath $certPath -Password $cred.Password
```

Step 3: Install the certificate in the root certificate store

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certPath -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\Root `
    -Password $cred.Password
```

Step 4: Verify the certificate again

```
$publicCert.Verify()
True
```

Then you can follow @BenN's instructions on how to use the certificate to perform decryption.